# Both (at least) WGM and PhD/doctorate

Tags: grandmaster, records, women, trivia

Similar to this question [Both grandmaster and PhD/doctorate](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36830/both-grandmaster-and-phd-doctorate) but for at least WGM (WGM, female IM, female GM, etc)

Among woman grandmasters, who have PhDs/doctorates?

**Conditions**:

1. standard WGM only eg no International Correspondence Chess WGM
2. no honourary PhDs/doctorates
3. maybe kind of a cheat but I'll allow JD/MD (and LLB to the extent that LLB=JD) i.e. doesn't have to be Doctor of Juridical Science/Doctor of Medical Sciences. Also the other stuff [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctorate#Types) eg doctor of education or doctor of engineering, just no honourary.

Answer (score 1):

What I got so far:

**Miscellaneous**

1. **Hou Yifan (SRZLY?)** **(UNSURE)**: same with the Robert Byrne thing as to what 'professor' means (i mean come on phd, really? i don't think so)
2. Kateřina Němcová - PhD in progress
3. 5-time and current (as of [Oct2021](https://www.ft.com/content/6f0d3325-d21a-4ef2-839d-4eafe2293151)) British women's chess champion [Harriet Hunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harriet_Hunt) - [PhD and Research Fellowship at Cambridge, specialising in archaeogenetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harriet_Hunt)
4. [Jana Krivec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jana_Krivec) - [psychology](https://thinkerspublishing.com/dr-jana-krivec-improve-your-life-by-playing-a-game-learn-how-to-turn-your-life-activities-into-lifelong-skills/) (not sure if PhD or PsyD)
5. [Alisa Marić](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alisa_Mari%C4%87) - PhD in economics.

**Law** (either JD/LLB or Doctor of Juridical Science)

1. [Xu Yuhua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xu_Yuhua): LLB
2. 9-time and current (as of Sep2021) British women's chess champion [Jovanka Houska](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/35171/why-is-jovanka-houska-introduced-as-a-wgm-when-she-holds-the-more-prestigious-im): [LLB](https://www.linkedin.com/in/jovanka-houska-64518249/)
3. [Natalia Pogonina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natalia_Pogonina#Personal_life): 'In 2008 Pogonina was studying for an MA in law at the Saratov State Academy of Law.'

**Medicine** (either MD or Doctor of Medical Sciences)

1. [Jana Bellin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jana_Bellin) - probably just MD

Comment: I'm not convinced Robert Byrne has more than a [masters degree](https://www.nytimes.com/2013/04/14/crosswords/chess/robert-byrne-chess-grandmaster-dies-at-84.html) from Indiana University.

Comment: It looks like Hou Yifan was awarded a Rhode's scholarship to study for a Master's of Public Policy at Oxford. I don't see anything about any scholarship activity between that and her professorship at Shenzhen University, so I assume that she has at most a Master's degree (I'm not sure if she finished her program at Oxford). Regardless, even if it isn't a PhD, it looks like she's had an impressive academic career outside of chess.